# Beyond: Two souls different versions?

Tags: ps3, version-differences

Installation of Beyond: Two souls from disc, will after update result in version **1.02,** and Approximately 3GB data installed.

BUT!
Downloaded from PlayStore, it's version **2.0,** and 31GB

does anybody know if there's any difference? (*except the size of course.*.)

Comment: I'm not sure of that, but maybe the major difference is the fact, that the PSStore version installs the complete game, instead of the blu-ray version, where some data is loaded from the disc. It sounds like a good explanation of installation size on storage.

Comment: @TravelerVihaan that part I completely agree, but the version is usually the same, but the difference between 1.02 and 2.0 is so big.. so something isn't right here..

Comment: Which country is the physical disc? There are different versions of the game, having some scenes to be removed (like a man being impaled or nudity) in order to reduce PEGI classification where needed. That could be the reason. Probably the digital one is the most censored.

Comment: @pinckerman it's eu, but even if there are different censured versions, the version number should still be the same